# Identity of concepts' intentional content

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, metaphilosophy, concept

I have recently read some articles about (lexical) concepts. Philosophers tend to think that, in order for two speakers to be able to communicate successfully, they must associate the *exact* same concepts with the same words. For example, my utterance of, say, "horse" must refer to an identical concept that your utterance of this same word, in the same context.
Now I am a bit confused about this notion of identity of concepts. Arguably, for two concepts to be identical, they must have the same intentional content. But this intentional content must not be confounded with what we take to be the concept's extension (otherwise we wouldn't be able to have genuine disagreements about questions like "is this a horse ?"). So the following is intuitively false:
(1) If two individuals share a same concept C, they must always agree on the extension of the word they use to express C.
I failed to find a correct formulation for the criterion of identity of two concepts' intentional content in the literature, but here is what I came with, based on my understanding:
(2) If two individuals share a same concept C, then they must agree on the extension of the word they use to express C, to the extent that their other beliefs involving C are similar, and that the individuals are rational.
Am I correct ? Is (2) a better formulation of the identity criterion than (1) ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/76436/9148)? There is no such thing as "exact same concept" for two different people. Intentional content always has individual variations, and speakers correct for that when interpreting each other. There is a difference between semantics ("literal" meaning) and pragmatics (use in context). Even if there was the same content, extensions can be different depending on how speakers apply the truth conditions in it, i.e. what they judge as true/false. Especially for vague concepts like "freedom" or "beauty".

Comment: @Conifold my previous post was about the criteria needed for concept possession. This one is specifically about concepts' intentional content (the intentional content of a concept does not provide a possession condition on its own, cognitive content also has a role to play). Regarding the notion of "exact same concept", it is definitely taken as a non negotiable condition for communication to be possible by most theorists.

Comment: @Conifold For example, D A. Weiskopf in  https://sk.sagepub.com/reference/encyclopedia-of-philosophy-and-the-social-sciences/n57.xml writes "Concepts are widely believed to be public, meaning that it is possible for many thinkers to possess the very same concept.". In the IEP, entry "concepts", Dennis Earl writes "concepts can be understood by different agents, so it seems that the very same concept can be represented in many different minds at once". Maybe there is a confusion in your comment (or my understanding of it) between "concepts" and what some authors have called "conceptions".

Comment: We also say that different screws from one production line are "the same" and do not mean it literally. Concepts are "the same" in relevant communicational respects, not in the sense of identical intentional content in individuals, which includes associations, connotations, "other beliefs involving C", etc. Such nuances do not matter in most practical contexts, making communication possible, but they may very well affect judgments, and hence extensions. Which is why rational people can disagree, "identical" beliefs and "identical" concepts do not translate into identical judgments.

Comment: @Conifold I think that we are, ironically, talking past to each other. I am concerned with the metaphysics of concepts, and your answers seem to address their epistemology. Metaphysically, two (token) concepts, each possessed by one individual, are of the same type only if they have the exact same intentional content. Now my question is: how to understand that identity criterion more precisely ? Surely pragmatics are involved when we ascribe concepts to an individual (cf. your comments to my last post), but I dont think that it helps answering the ontological question I am asking here.

Comment: Perhaps we do not share the concept of "intentional content", to me it is associated with Husserl and phenomenology. Is it by any chance the same as "propositional content" used in analytic semantics, i.e., roughly, truth conditions? Also, what is your metaphysics of concepts? Platonism, nominalism, inferentialism?

Comment: @Conifold I am borrowing the expression "intentional content" from Jesse Prinz's "Furnishing the mind". He defines the intentional content of a concept as the set of things the concept refers to, in the actual and in possible worlds (so it is much similar to what we call the referents of linguistic tokens, or to what some call the possible-worlds extension). This it not to be conflated with what we *take* the concept to refer to, e.g. by using our categorization abilities. For example, when in the dark, I can take a cow to be a horse...

Comment: @Conifold ... Yet the intentional content of the concept to which I refer by saying "horse" has not changed: taking something to be a horse doesn't make it a horse. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to realize my mistake when in better light conditions. As for my prefered metaphysics of concepts, I do not thing it is relevant to the question I ask: whatever you take universals to be, the question of identity between concepts has to be asked, and the answer probably does not much depend on the metaphysical theory you endorse.

Comment: I disagree on metaphysics, inferentialists do not describe concepts in terms of content, and nominalists often do not adopt a robust notion of content either. The question seems to presuppose metaphysics with a Platonist flavor, at least of abstract objects kind. And this choice pretty much determines the answer to your question: intension determines extension simply by definition. Note that this is incompatible with semantic externalism as well, if concepts are codetermined by environment "what's in the head" can not determine extension.

Comment: @Conifold Inferentialists do not individuate concepts on the basis of their content, but they would not deny that if two (token) concepts are of the same type, then they do indeed have the same intentional content. See for example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242448877_Are_Concepts_Public, where E. Lalumera, although defending inferentialist theories of concepts, states that the weakest sense of concepts sharing between individuals needs at least identity of referent. The same goes for nominalists (see the IEP entry "concepts", under the metaphysics section).

Comment: They do deny it, "*none of these similarities require perfect identity of concepts*", and the same applies to Lalumera's identity of reference. The talk of types and tokens that treats "content" like an entity is not germaine to inferentialism, it is a platonist reification, at least a fictional version of it. There is no tight link between inferential roles in the "*game of giving and asking for reasons*", as Brandom puts it, and extension, see his [Conceptual Content and Discursive Practice](https://www.academia.edu/12652582/Conceptual_Content_and_Discursive_Practice).

Comment: @Conifold Your quote of Clark and Prinz seems irrelevant to our disagreement. Their article was precisely aimed at arguing that concepts publicity does not require concepts identity. But in this article they obviously take for granted that for two (token) concepts to be shared, they must have the exact same intentional content (their point is, however, that the concepts' cognitive content can be slightly different). This is especially obvious in Lalumera's discussion, but also in Fodor's article that Clark and Prinz refer to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113701/discussion-between-user47679-and-conifold).